# Cannot use animated charts with react-native expo

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-reanimated

I am trying to use [@rainbow-me/animated-charts](https://github.com/rainbow-me/react-native-animated-charts) with expo. Application stops when I try to render component without any log. Am I missing something?

```
    data = [
    { x: 1453075200, y: 1.47 },
    { x: 1453161600, y: 1.37 },
    { x: 1453248000, y: 1.53 },
    { x: 1453334400, y: 1.54 },
    { x: 1453420800, y: 1.52 },
    { x: 1453507200, y: 2.03 },
    { x: 1453593600, y: 2.1 },
    { x: 1453680000, y: 2.5 },
    { x: 1453766400, y: 2.3 },
    { x: 1453852800, y: 2.42 },
    { x: 1453939200, y: 2.55 },
    { x: 1454025600, y: 2.41 },
    { x: 1454112000, y: 2.43 },
    { x: 1454198400, y: 2.2 },
  ];

  let points = monotoneCubicInterpolation(data)(40);

  return (
    <View style={{ ...containerStyle }}>
      {data.length > 0 && (
        <ChartPathProvider
          data={{
            points,
            smoothingStrategy: 'bezier',
          }}
        >
          <ChartPath
            heigh={150}
            width={SIZES.width}
            stroke={COLORS.lightGreen}
            stokeWidth={2}
          />
        </ChartPathProvider>
      )}
    </View>
  );
```

I also included 'react-native-reanimated/plugin' as mention in docs.

Answer (score 0):

```
const points = monotoneCubicInterpolation({data, range: 40});
```

Hey, I'm facing a different error with this library myself but by looking at your code and the docs double check how you're calling the function `monotoneCubicInterpolation` I hope this helps!